# Issues building pywinhook from source

Tags: c, python-3.x, pyhook

**Python interpreter:** 3.7

**Python library:** pywinhook https://pypi.org/project/pyWinhook/.

**Objective:** Add some features or functions to pywinhook library.

**Tutorial to build this library:** This library was done from pyHook library. That is why I am using the following tutorial to build this library https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Build_Instructions/.

**Steps done:** I downloaded the source code of the library. I installed the MinGW and SWIG. I added the environment variables required.

**Issues:** When I am executing *python setup.py build -cmingw32*, I got the following error and I could not continue with the process. If someone could explain to me what I should do. Thanks in advance

The last lines of the execution was:

```
build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pywinhook\cpyhook_wrap.o:cpyHook_wrap.c:(.text+0x1bb6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyEval_RestoreThread'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and based on the link shared by @Juan Botero, I realized that I am compiling in 64-bit. The solution was as follows:

1. Download MinGW-w64 on https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
2. Add the following statement in the file cygwinccompiler.py, due to I am using an updated version of VB.

   elif msc_ver == '1900':
   return ['msvcr100']
3. I run the instruction written in the tutorial and it works.

Answer (score 2):

searching for the error: undefined reference to `_imp__PyEval_RestoreThread'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I got this,it may help.

https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/issues/224

Comment: Tks @Juan Botero for your help. I posted my answer below. Sorry for the delayed answer but It took me a lot to understand the error.